# simplexml_load_string() and doing json_encode() throwing encoding error how to make it to utf-8 json and more compatible?

Tags: javascript, python, php, json, xml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($SourceData);
$json = json_encode($xml);
echo $json
```

is working fine in front end java script environment but when requesting the URL in python , im getting encoding error "cant decode char at position"

is there any work around?

i tried changing the python output to utf-8. still come error is coming.
is it related to request method?

Comment: Please provide some code, so we can reproduce the issue. Maybe even some links to code here. You can add python and php code. https://paiza.io/en

Comment: thanks for offering help, turns out that sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8') worked well. i have no problem in windows 10 but on windows 7 i had this issue. maybe due to environment.